# Precedência de operadores

Tags: java, operadores

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a precedência de operadores em Java. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
int x = 2;
long y = 1 + x * 4 - ++x;
```

Visualizando a tabela de precedência [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Ao meu ver a expressão deveria ser resolvida da seguinte forma:

```
1 + x * 4 - 3
1 + 3 * 4 - 3
1 + 12 - 3
y=10
```

Ao contrário do que coloquei, a resposta dada pelo programa em execução é `y=6`. Gostaria de saber porque ele realizou a multiplicação antes do incremento?

Pela tabela de precedência, incremento ao meu ver deveria ser realizado primeiro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seu erro foi supor que a sub-expressão `++x` seria avaliada *antes* da sub-expressão `x * 4`. No momento que esta expressão é avaliada, `x` ainda vale `2`, de modo que a resolução correta é:

```
(1 + (x * 4)) - (++x)   [x=2]
(1 + (2 * 4)) - (++x)   [x=2]
(1 + 8) - (++x)         [x=2]
9 - (++x)               [x=2]
9 - x                   [x=3]
9 - 3                   [x=3]
6                       [x=3]
```

A precedência dos operadores refere-se somente a "onde colocar os parênteses" na expressão. A avaliação, contudo, ocorre da esquerda pra direita, tal como tudo mais na linguagem de programação (ex.: ordem de avaliação dos argumentos de uma função, ordem de execução das instruções, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Por que também existe a associatividade que é da esquerda para a direita. Ele não analisa todos os operadores e escolhe qual vai executar primeiro. Ele vai fazendo isto com os operandos, normalmente em duplas, da esquerda para a direita na maior parte dos casos. Só muda a direção quando a associatividade é inversa como é o caso, por exemplo, dos operadores de atribuição.

Então a multiplicação não está se misturando com com a operação de incrimento, ela é executada antes de tomar conhecimento que haverá este operação.

[Tabela de precedência com associatividade](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

O ideal é evitar usar operadores que causem efeitos colaterais em expressões maiores, normalmente o operador de incremento é melhor usado de forma isolada ou quando seu isolamento fica claro.

Comment: Ainda que os operadores de soma e subtração associassem à direita, a ordem de execução relativa entre `x*4` e `++x` ainda seria a mesma. `1 + ((x * 4) - (++x))`. E nesse caso particular, até o resultado seria o mesmo (não seria o caso se o primeiro operador fosse um `-`)

Comment: Sim, neste caso sim, mas o que ele está imaginando é que não há nenhuma associatividade e a expressão é avaliada como um todo. Ele acha que porque o incremento é precedente ele deve ser avaliado primeiro mesmo estando na direita, e depois ir para os outros operadores.

Comment: Acho que eu entendi o que você quis dizer. De fato, uma expressão sem efeitos colaterais poderia ser avaliada na ordem "folhas primeiro, subindo em direção à raiz" (i.e. operações mais precedentes sendo aplicadas antes das menos precedentes), e o resultado seria o mesmo que "galho da esquerda primeiro, galho da direita depois". Com efeitos colaterais, os resultados são diferentes. Mas note que isso é uma convenção arbitrária imposta pela linguagem de programação, pois a forma de incluir parênteses segundo a precedência e associatividade seria a mesma em ambos os casos.

Comment: Sim, concordo..

Answer (score 0):

A expressão é da esquerda para a direita. Sendo assim:

```
int x = 2;
long y = 1 + x * 4 - ++x;
```

```
1 + 2 * 4 - ++x;
1 + 8 - ++2;
1 + 8 - 3;
9 - 3;
6
```