# Por que o if funciona apenas com o retorno de um método?

Tags: java, if, condição, booleano

Segue o meu código que contém um método booleano:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ativ16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, i, v[];
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = entrada.nextInt();
        v = new int[n];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
            v[i] = entrada.nextInt();
        }


        if (VetorEhPalindromo(v, n)) {
            System.out.println("vetor é palíndromo");
        } else {
            System.out.println("vetor não é palíndromo");
        }
    }

    static boolean VetorEhPalindromo(int v[], int n) {

        int i, temp;
        int t[] = new int[v.length];
        boolean ehPalindromo = false;

        for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            t[i] = v[i];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {

            if (i < (t.length / 2)) {
                temp = t[i];
                t[i] = t[t.length - i - 1];
                t[t.length - i - 1] = temp;
            }

        }

        for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {

            if (t[i] == v[i]) {
                ehPalindromo = true;
            } else {
                ehPalindromo = false;
            }
        }

        return ehPalindromo;
    }
}
```

A minha dúvida é a respeito do condicional `if` no método `main()`. Por que o `if(VetorEhPalindromo(v,n))` não recebe uma condição e ainda assim executa o código corretamente? Por exemplo: `if(VetorEhPalindromo(v, n) == true`).

Comment: Não entendi qual é a dúvida. O método retorna um booleano, então qual é o problema?

Comment: @bigown acho que é pelo fato do retorno do método citado ser a condição do if apenas.

Comment: O simples fato do método retornar um booleano já representa uma condição pro `if` verificar. Lembre-se, o if avalia uma condição como `true` ou `false`, se o método por si já retorna isso, seu retorno que é a condição verificada.

Comment: Então por padrão sempre que eu apenas chamar a função dentro do if, o programa entende como uma condição do tipo função == true?

Comment: @Leko em java não precisa comparar retornos booleanos dessa forma, a tipagem não vai permitir você usar nenhuma condição que não seja uma operação lógica(com retorno true ou false). Fazendo uma analogia ao idioma, usar `if(VetorEhPalindromo() == true)` ao inves de `if(VetorEhPalindromo())` soaria como um [pleonasmo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmo). Não é um erro de sintaxe, apenas aumenta um pouco a complexidade de forma desnecessária. Por isso que funciona.

Comment: @seamusd o titulo ficou bem estranhho após a edição(na verdade ja estava, mas ficou mais ainda)

Comment: @diegofm percebi que estava mesmo estranho. A questão da edição foi porque percebi parte do título estava na tag, então talvez seria melhor deixar sem. Mas você tem razão.

Comment: @diegofm tentei melhorar isso, acho que ficou melhor desta forma.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Veja este código:

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        boolean cond = x == 10;
        System.out.println(cond);
        if (cond) System.out.println("executou");
        cond = metodo();
        System.out.println(cond);
        if (cond) System.out.println("executou");
        System.out.println(x == 10);
        if (x == 10) System.out.println("executou");
        System.out.println(metodo());
        if (metodo()) System.out.println("executou");
    }
    public static boolean metodo() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vMec7P). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/grbnszmw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/IfAnalysis.java).

Muita gente deve surpreender-se que é possível guardar o resultado da expressão booleana, que as pessoas costumam chamar de condição. Veja mais em [Atribuir uma expressão a uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44741/101).

O primeiro dia que vi algo sobre o assunto em programação na hora percebi que isso era o normal, eu estava na oitava série, nem tinha formação matemática completa, mas sabia o básico que todo mundo deveria saber. Eu tive a sorte de começar aprender por baixo. Hoje as pessoas aprendem o que vem por cima sem ter o fundamento.

Uma coisa que muito programador iniciante não entende, e incrivelmente até alguns com anos de experiência, é que um `if` executará o bloco de comando, ou passará por ele sem executar, baseado em um **valor** booleano, ou seja, se tiver um valor verdadeiro entra no bloco, se tiver falso então não entra no bloco, entrará no `else` se tiver. É só isso que o `if` faz, qualquer outra coisa não é função dele, se por acaso tiver outras coisas acontecendo ali, é independente do `if` e na prática será executado antes, seu resultado será armazenado temporariamente em algum lugar para ser usado pelo `if`.

De onde vem esse valor booleano? Pode vir de uma expressão qualquer, desde que o resultado seja um `true` ou um `false`. É comum que essa expressão use um operador de comparação (`==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`), afinal eles geram sempre um resultado booleano. Operadores relacionais (`&&`, `||`, `!`) também geram um booleano, esses últimos inclusive exigem que os operandos sejam booleanos também (isso não vale para algumas linguagens de tipagaem fraca).

Mas se usar uma variável que já guarde um valor booleano? Isso é uma expressão simples que gera um resultado booleano e pode ser usado no `if` sem problema, ele tem o que é esperado.

Assim como você usa uma "variável inteira" para fazer uma conta, por que não usar uma "variável booleana" para estabelecer uma condição? Seria estranho não fazer isso, seria assimétrico. Então pode-se fazer:

```
int x = 1;
int y = x + 5;
```

no lugar de

```
int y = 1 + 5
```

Por que não poderia fazer o que está no exemplo acima?

E se em vez de usar uma variável eu usar um método que retorne um booleano? Não dará o mesmo resultado? Não fornecerá exatamente o que eu preciso para usar no `if`?

O que eu percebo é que as pessoas acham que o `if` é algo especial, e ele não é, ele só faz o que eu descrevi acima. Na verdade ["toda" linguagem é montada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101) de forma o mais simétrica possível. Onde vale uma coisa vale para tudo. Se em algum lugar não puder valer faz-se uma exceção justificada na sua [especificação e implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101).

Assim como eu não compreendo porque programadores criam variáveis sem necessidade alguma<sup>*</sup> ([variáveis são apenas uma forma de armazenamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), se não precisa armazenar, pra que criá-la?), não entendo porque as pessoas acham que é obrigado fazer

```
if (metodo() == true)
```

Na verdade isso é absolutamente redundante tomando o exemplo acima. Isso seria o mesmo que fazer

```
x = x; //sim, está só atribuindo o valor de x em x, todo mundo vê a redundância.
```

Nesse exemplo está pegando o valor que o método retorna, no caso sabemos que é `true` e compara para saber se ele é `true`, portanto dará `true`. Porque não usar logo o valor recebido se é isso que queremos? Pra que criar um passo adicional que faz nada além do que já sabemos? Vejo "cada desculpa" quando o programador é pego fazendo uma bobagem dessas...

Quando vezes vejo métodos fazerem algo assim:

```
public boolean condicao(int x) {
    if (x == 10) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Quando basta fazer apenas:

```
public boolean condicao(int x) {
    return x == 10; //retorna exatamente o que precisava
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Condition.java).

Quando vejo isso sei que o código daquela pessoa terá muitas coisas erradas porque ela não tem a menor noção de coisas básicas da computação, ou até mesmo da matemática, e só conseguirá seguir receitas, o que está longe de ser programação de fato.

Eu acho que o problema é até esse mesmo. As pessoas não enxergam que o `if` elimina uma variável que todo mundo acha que é necessária sempre.

### Como as linguagens funcionam

Esquece esse negócio de condição, o que existe é uma expressão booleana. Não tem mágica, não tem nada especial, se não fosse assim é que seria especial. Isso tudo nem é programação, isso é matemática (básica), nada mais que isso. Uma pessoa que aprendeu matemática por completo entende isso sem ler um material de programação.

Linguagens têm regras bem definidas de como elas funcionam e elas tentam ser o mais intuitivas possível, tentam ser lineares, simétricas, fazendo apenas o óbvio.

Tudo que é escrito é executado em pares de valores (algumas coisas podem executar sozinhas ou nem precisar de um valor, mas jamais em trios ou mais elementos) e sempre uma instrução do que deve fazer com o valor. Isso tem uma certa simplificação na explicação, o resto não vem ao caso.

Um `if` é fruto de um valor booleano que é avaliado e decide se desvia a execução para outro ponto ou mantêm a sequência. Além disso ele possui [desvios incondicionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101) escondidos para controlar o bloco. Esse valor booleano deve ser algo único. Se ele não é único ele deve executar a expressão que está escrita ali para dar o resultado único. Se essa expressão tem sub-expressões (pares de operados com um operador), cada uma delas precisa ser executada antes, conforme ordem de [precedência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98602/101).

Na verdade você também funciona assim. Para avaliar uma expressão completa, seu cérebro vai avaliando sub-expressões, você faz "uma continha" de cada vez e vai pegando o resultado para usar na próxima continha, até que, de passo em passo, fez a "contona" que deu o resultado final. Como pode ser visto [aqui](http://composingprograms.com/versions/v1/pages/12-elements-of-programming.html):

[image: Avaliação de expressão]

Por isso que eu falo que a primeira linguagem que alguém deve aprender é Assembly (ainda que só o superficial). Entender como o computador funciona antes de criar abstrações. É muito difícil entender como as coisas são quando a abstração vem primeiro.

Veja [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101) para ajudar ter uma ideia como isso funciona. Dê atenção para a árvore abstrata de sintaxe que é disso que estou falando no parágrafo anterior ao diagrama. É assim porque o computador só consegue executar operações concretas muito simples, o resto é abstração em cima disso.

Alguns "programadores" morrem sem entender isso. Na verdade sempre foram seguidores de regras que eu sempre falo, nunca foram programadores. Existe uma diferença entre programar e escrever um punhado de código que a pessoa sequer entende o que faz. Por sorte alguns são curiosos, perguntam e aprendem, pra isso estamos aqui.

---

<sup>*</sup>Criação de variável sem razão aparente, nem mesmo de documentação é o caso mais óbvio da pessoa estar seguindo receitas de bolo sem entender o que está fazendo. Outro exemplo muito comum é declarar uma variável antes e logo em seguida [atribuir seu valor ao invés de fazer tudo de uma vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101). Eu entendo porque as pessoas declaram todas variáveis no começo da função ou método, elas aprenderam errado que isso é bom. Aprenderam assim porque linguagens antigas obrigavam ser assim, mas o mais correto é sua declaração ser o mais perto possível de seu uso e com o menor escopo possível. Dentro do menor [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) possível.

Answer (score 6):

É simples entender. If testa uma condição, se a condição é satisfeita então a condição retorna true. Logo se você testar um Boolean já estará dando o resultado ao IF.

Veja o exemplo para você entender:

**Teste de "afirmação"**

```
    Boolean teste = true;
if(teste){
// Vai entrar aqui porque teste é verdadeiro
} else {
// Não vai entrar aqui porque a condição já foi satisfeita
}
```

**Teste de negação**

Já se você colocar um ! antes da varriável na condicional seu teste será inverso, ou seja ao invés de você estar testando se a condição se satisfaz você estará testando se a condição não se satisfaz

```
    Boolean teste = true;
if(!teste){
// Não vai entrar aqui porque teste é verdadeiro
} else {
// Vai entrar aqui porque teste é verdadeiro e o if está testando se a condição NÃO foi satisfeita
}
```