# Campo dentro de uma variável dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Segue o código abaixo:

JavaScript:

```
var img1 = false;
var img2 = true;

var img =  "img"+1;      //Resultado da variavel img é "img1".
                         //Como converter string para variável ?
                         //Exemplo: "img1" para img1

      if (img == false) //Errado ----> "img1" == false
      {                 //Certo -----> img1 == false ou seja false = false

      }
```

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Porque não usa um *array*? É muito melhor e não precisa dessa gambiarra..

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo concreto do que precisas fazer?

Comment: Oi @bigown, pode crê

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quiser insistir nisso pode fazer algo assim:

```js
var img1 = false;
var img2 = true;
var img = eval("img" + 1);
if (!img) console.log("ok");
```

Mas [evite usar o `eval()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101). O correto é fazer com um *array*:

```js
var img = [false, true];
var img = img[0];
if (!img) console.log("ok");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/InnerVariable.js).

Dependendo do contexto uma outra solução pode ser mais adequada.

Troquei o `img == false` por `!img` se tiver dúvida quanto a isso leia [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165494/101).

Comment: Podes tambem usar string-casting - que é muito mais safe: `var img1 = 'hello'; var nome = "img"; console.log(window[''+nome+1])` (mas mais martelo ainda ;D)

Comment: @MoshMage tb, é tudo gambiarra, o *array* é a solução correta.

Comment: Sim. Há-de ser o que ele quer *mas nao o que ele perguntou* :P

Comment: Oi @bigown, me ajudou muito. Array é muito útil.

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de fazer desse modo usa array

```
vetor = new Array(false,true); //declarando e iniciando a array
var img = vetor[0]; //atribuindo o valor da posição 0 da array para a variavel 
if(img == false) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que você precisa de um código assim:

```
function foobar() {
   this.img1 = false;
   this.img2 = true;

   var img = this['img'.concat(1)];
   if (img == false) {
       alert("Falso!");
   }
   else {
       alert(img);
   }
}
new foobar();
```

Se estiver em um contexto global (fora de uma `function`), você pode trocar `this`por `window`. A função `concat()` irá realizar a concatenação, gerando `a1`.