# Erro CS0029 - Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "int" em "bool" em função de C#

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, return

O código recebe um número do usuário e imprimir **caso seja positivo para True e caso seja negativo para False**, só que há um erro de tipos acontecendo e não entendo como resolver.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace F1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero;
            Write("Digite um número: ");
            numero = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            WriteLine($"{Verificar(numero)}");
            ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }

        public static bool Verificar(int numero)
        {
            if (numero > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (numero < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return numero;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro é exatamente o que está mostrando, você está tentando retornar um número onde se espera um booleano. E olhando o código não faz o menor sentido nem mesmo fazer esse retorno. Seria interessante interpretar a mensagem de erro e procurar onde está ocorrendo.

No caso era aquele `return numero;` que não faz sentido algum estar ali. Se deseja retornar se é positivo ou não basta retornar o booleano, não tem porque retornar o número, se precisa retornar o número precisaria fazer outras coisa (e possivelmente mudar o nome do método), mas sem um requisito nem vou me arriscar tentar fazer isto, não parece que precisa disto.

Seria simples assim (note que eu consertei outros problemas que já foram mostrados antes e que você se recusa a consertar porque não quebra a aplicação em todos os casos:

```
using static System.Console;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Write("Digite um número: ");
        if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var numero)) return;
        WriteLine($"{ÉPositivo(numero)}");
    }
    public static bool ÉPositivo(int numero) => numero >= 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Laddzl). E [no **.NET Fidlle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qG9N95). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/ReturnCompatible.cs).

Percebeu que a quantidade de linhas e caracteres do código é muito menor e mantendo uma lógica limpa? E também consertei um erro de interpretação do que é um número positivo (o 0 também é um positivo). E dei um nome significativo para o método, porque se for para dar um nome que não quer dizer nada nem precisava do método de tão simples que é e aí poderia fazer a comparação de forma direta no código, mas entendo que quer a abstração do método.

Uma expressão booleana já resulta em booleano então não tem porque usar um `if`, neste caso basta retornar o resultado da própria expressão. É necessário entender o que cada coisa faz no código caso contrário nunca aprenderá programar, estará só repetindo códigos que já viu antes em algum lugar.

Importante para aprender mais sobre: [Por que o if funciona apenas com o retorno de um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165494/101).

Comment: Não tinha visto que já tinha uma resposta. Elas dizem a mesma coisa. Pergunto, o correto é  remover minha resposta?

Comment: Não tem porque, a sua dá uma explicação diferente.

Answer (score 4):

O `C#` é tipificado estaticamente em tempo de compilação, depois que uma variável é declarada, ela não pode ser declarada novamente ou atribuída a um valor de outro tipo, a menos que esse tipo possa ser convertido implicitamente no tipo da variável.

O a assinatura do método `Verificar()` especifica que o tipo do retorno é `bool`. Na linha...

```
return numero;
```

...é retornado `numero` que é tipo `int` onde ocorre o erro:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

É possível identificar dois erros no seu código:

1. A tentativa de retornar um inteiro no lugar de um valor lógico.
2. Seu método `Verificar()` não cobre todas as possibilidades de
   entradas numéricas. Se `numero` for igual a zero o método não
   consegue classificar pois as verificações são `numero > 0` e `numero < 0` e ambas não incluem o caso `numero == 0`.

Olhando a documentação dos [operadores de comparação C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators) verifica-se que os operadores relacionais `==`, `<`, `>`, `<=` e `>=` comparam seus operandos e retornam um `bool`.

Ciente disso basta simplificar o método `Verificar()` usando de uma comparação que cubra todo o espectro numérico suportado pelo tipo `int`.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace F1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero;
            Write("Digite um número: ");
            numero = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            WriteLine($"{Verificar(numero)}");
            ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }

        public static bool Verificar(int numero)
        {
            // Se numero for maior ou igual a zero retorna true caso contrário retorna false.
            return numero >= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Devido a simplicidade da operação realizada dentro do método 'Verificar()' é possível eliminar esse método e transferir essa comparação `numero >= 0` para dentro`do corpo do método Main()`.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace F1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero;
            Write("Digite um número: ");
            numero = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            WriteLine($"{numero >= 0}");
            ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: É necessário usar o método `Verificar()`

Comment: @CarlosA., Imaginando essa possibilidade que coloquei dois códigos na resposta um com `Verificar()` e o outro sem `Verificar()`

Comment: Esse jeito sem o método também é interessante que retorna o resultado.