# Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "decimal" em "int" em código de função de C#

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Esse código faz a média aritmética ou ponderada das 3 notas de aluno com base em sua escolha de média conforme o uso do `Equals`, o erro do código é exatamente essa conversão de `decimal` para `int`, como realizar corretamente essa conversão?

```
using static System.Console;

namespace Função1
{
    class Class4
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal nota1 = 0, nota2 = 0, nota3 = 0;
            string letra;
            Write("Digite a 1ª nota: ");
            nota1 = decimal.Parse(ReadLine());
            Write("Digite a 2ª nota: ");
            nota2 = decimal.Parse(ReadLine());
            Write("Digite a 3ª nota: ");
            nota3 = decimal.Parse(ReadLine());
            Write("Digite ou A para calcular a média aritmética ou P para calcular a média ponderada: ");
            letra = ReadLine();
            WriteLine($"{Calcula(nota1, nota2, nota3, letra)}");
            ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }

        static int Calcula(decimal nota1, decimal nota2, decimal nota3, string letra)
        {
            decimal media = 0;
            if (letra.Equals("A"))
            {
                media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3;
                Write("A opção digitada foi um média aritmética");
            }
            else if (letra.Equals("P"))
            {
                media = ((nota1 * 5) + (nota2 * 3) + (nota3 * 2)) / (5 + 3 + 2);
                Write("A opção digitada foi um média pnderada");
            }
            return media;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Carlos, você quer que a média seja um número inteiro ou decimal?

Comment: A média nesses casos tem que ser decimal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É o mesmo problema da [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415713/101) só que agora a solução é diferente. O tipo de retorno  do método tem que bater com o que está sendo retornando, então se o método realmente tem que retornar `int` retorne `int` e não `decimal`, se por outro lado ele deve retornar `decimal` então mude o tipo de retorno do método, encolha qual é a melhor solução para o problema, me parece que é trocar o tipo do retorno do método para `decimal`, alfo assim:

```
static decimal Calcula(decimal nota1, decimal nota2, decimal nota3, string letra)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/RightTypeToCalc.cs).

Faça qualquer dessas duas coisas mas não faz sentido converter o número `decimal` para `int` porque está jogando fora uma parte do valor calculado. Eu acho que deseja manter o alor calculado, mas se não desejasse, então tudo deveria ser inteiro e não desperdiçar recursos para jogar fora o que obteve (não digo isso por causa da pergunta mas sim por causa da outra resposta).

Não vou tentar resolver os outros problemas do código, por exemplo o uso do `Equals()` que não chega ser um erro, mas não é idiomático. Por exemplo isto deveria ser dois métodos e não um parametrizado o que fazer.

Comment: Estou resolvendo esses outros problemas

Answer (score 4):

Refiz a questão melhorando alguns valores e ficou assim:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace Função1
{
    class Class4
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Utilize vírgula nos valores decimais(Ex: 7, 5 ao invés de 7.5)
            string letra;
            Write("Digite a 1ª nota: ");
            if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal nota1)) return 1;
            Write("Digite a 2ª nota: ");
            if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal nota2)) return 1;
            Write("Digite a 3ª nota: ");
            if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal nota3)) return 1;
            Write("Digite ou A para calcular a média aritmética ou P para calcular a média ponderada: ");
            letra = ReadLine();
            WriteLine($"Média: {Calcula(nota1, nota2, nota3, letra)}");
            ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }

        static decimal Calcula(decimal nota1, decimal nota2, decimal nota3, string letra)
        {
            decimal media = 0;
            if (letra.Equals("A"))
            {
                media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3;
                WriteLine("A opção digitada foi um média aritmética");
            }
            else if (letra.Equals("P"))
            {
                media = ((nota1 * 5) + (nota2 * 3) + (nota3 * 2)) / (5 + 3 + 2);
                WriteLine("A opção digitada foi um média ponderada");
            }
            return System.Math.Round(media, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*Como realizar corretamente essa conversão?*

Simplesmente converta de `decimal` para `int`:

`return Decimal.ToInt32(media);`