# Erro CS7036 no C# ao invocar uma função

Tags: c#, .net, método, parâmetros

Acabei de entrar na matéria de funções e métodos e já me deparei com um problema que não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum por não entender o porquê dele.

A questão é:

> "Crie um método que receba um número inteiro e informe se ele é
>   positivo (true) ou negativo (false) através de um retorno com
>   boolean."

Meu código ficou assim:

```
class Program
    {
        static bool PositivoOuNegativo (int Numero, bool Resultado)
        {
            if (Numero >= 0)
            {
                Resultado = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Resultado = false;
            }
            return Resultado;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numeroTeste;
            bool ResultadoTeste;
            Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
            numeroTeste = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            ResultadoTeste = PositivoOuNegativo(numeroTeste);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Mas está aparecendo o erro:

> CS7036 Não há nenhum argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parametro
>   formal necessário "Resultado" de "Program.PositivoOuNegativo(int,
>   bool)".

Aonde estou errando e como proceder?

Comment: você definiu a função para receber 2 argumentos, `int Numero, bool Resultado` mas deve ter apenas um, o resultado é retornado pela função ao final dela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você prestar bem atenção na mensagem de erro já tem claro qual é o problema, só falta a solução. E alguém ingênuo poderia dizer que tem que chamar o método passando dois argumentos e não apenas um como está fazendo. Só que este método com dois parâmetros não faz sentido e é um método que poderia ser muito mais simples. Aproveitando e consertando outros problemas seria isto:

```
using static System.Console;

class Program {
    static bool ÉPositivo(int numero) => numero >= 0;
    static void Main() {
        Write("Digite um número: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var numero)) return;
        WriteLine(ÉPositivo(numero));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oIxPRi). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVV8dp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Posisitve.cs).

Note que o método já retorna se é positivo então não tem porque ter esse segundo parâmetro, o resultado é passado pelo retorno. E mudei o nome do método porque ele não diz se é positivo ou negativo, ele diz se é positivo ou não. E como uma expressão booleana já dá o resultado esperado não tem porque usar `if`, isto é código em excesso fazendo obviedade desnecessária, o resultado da expressão já é o retorno. Usei a sintaxe simplificada que não exige usar o `return`.

Também simplifiquei o pedido do dado e fiz a conversão do jeito certo para não quebrar a aplicação se a pessoa digitar algo inválido. Eu encerrei, mas poderia colocar uma mensagem de erro ali.

Caiu de 23 para 6 linhas, bem fácil de acompanhar, não?

Seria legal ver isto: [Por que o if funciona apenas com o retorno de um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165494/101).

Comment: Entendi, não posso declarar dois métodos e depois ao chamar a função só usar um, certo? Arrumei e simplifiquei aqui. Valeu!